# Problem accessing images uploaded to heroku thru RoR application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to upload a image from application and then trying to access it from another page. The code used for uploading the image is as follows:

```
uploaded_io = params[:recipe][:picture]                  
  File.open(Rails.root.join('recipe_images',uploaded_io.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
  file.write(uploaded_io.read)
end
```

This works fine when on the local development environment, however when I load the application on Heroku and try to access the image I get the following error:

```
(No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /app/recipe_images/logo.jpeg):
```

I tried creating a folder `recipe_images` in the `app` folder but again get the same issue.

For accessing the uploaded image I am using the following code in my view:

```
<%= image_tag("recipe_images/logo.jpeg"%>
```

This again works on the development environment but fails on production since the image is not there.

Why isn't this working on Heroku?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why this isn't working right after you accept an image, but you shouldn't be storing uploaded images on Heroku's local filesystem anyway. That filesystem [is ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem): any changes you make to it will be lost the next time your dyno restarts. This [happens frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts) (at least once per day).

Instead, Heroku [recommends](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3) using something like Amazon S3 for uploads and provides [a guide for doing so with Rails](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails).